# How to load inner html of div from another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a website where the navigation bar links would seamlessly lead to another page with fading transitions without loading.

When the links are clicked, the `div#page` block, which has the main page content and the footer, would fade out, empty itself, and fade back in with the content of the `href` of the clicked link. However, my current code, seen below, placing the html of the entire page (including the `head` contents) on `div#page` instead of just the inner HTML of `div#page`.

```
$("#header .menu a, #header .logo").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var title = $(this).attr("title");

    history.pushState(null, title, href);

    $("#page").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#page").delay(1000).empty();
    });

    $("#page").load(href + "#page", function() {
        $("#page").fadeIn();
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`docs`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

So try adding a white-space like so

```
$("#page").load(href + " #page", function() { //White space before #page
    $("#page").fadeIn();
});
```

**PS:** I have not tested this code.

Comment: Yeah that's probably how it differentiates whether to display the full content or partially.

Comment: I didn't knew that. Less struggle than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. The recommended way would be to create an API that would return the
   inner HTML only.
2. Parse the response like so (example):

   ```
   var $dom = $('<div />');
   $dom.html(response);
   var $content = $dom.find('#id'); // #id is your inner content id
   ```

And now you should be able to insert the inner content using `$content.html()`.